# Run .bat file from powershell

Tags: powershell, rabbitmqctl

I am trying to run a batch file from powershell. I would like to get the response but it is failing. If I run the .bat file:

```
rabbitmqctl.bat -n rabbit@xxx-123 ping
```

I get the following response:

> Ping succeeded

However when I run it through powershell:

```
$test = Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Program Files\RabbitMQ\rabbitmq_server-3.10.7\sbin\rabbitmqctl.bat" -WindowStyle Hidden -ArgumentList "-n rabbit@xxx-123 ping"  -Wait -PassThru;
```

`$test` variable is empty.

Any help?

Comment: In PowerShell, try `$test = rabbitmqctl.bat -n rabbit@xxx-123 ping`.  If `rabbitmqctl.bat` is not in the $Env:Path, they you will need to specify a directory path to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- **To synchronously execute console applications or batch files in the current console window, call them *directly***.

  - This allows you to *capture their output directly* and to *query their exit code* via [automatic **`$LASTEXITCODE`** variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#lastexitcode).
- **Do *not* use [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process)** (or the `System.Diagnostics.Process` API it is based on), except if truly necessary.

  - Specifically, you can *not* directly capture the output from an executable launched from a `Start-Process` call; the only in-memory output you can capture - assuming you use the `-PassThru` switch - is a [`System.Diagnostics.Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Diagnostics.Process) instance describing the launched process.
  - [GitHub docs issue #6239](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/PowerShell-Docs/issues/6239) provides guidance on when use of `Start-Process` is and isn't appropriate.

Therefore:

```bash
$test = 
  & 'C:\Program Files\RabbitMQ\rabbitmq_server-3.10.7\sbin\rabbitmqctl.bat' -n rabbit@xxx-123 ping
```

Note:

- ***Generally*, you can call executables and batch files  with arguments *as you would from `cmd.exe`***, though there are some **PowerShell-specific requirements**:

  - Because your specific batch-file path requires *quoting*, use of `&`, the [call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#call-operator-), is needed (you may choose to *always* use it, but it is only necessary for commands (executable paths) that are *quoted* and/or contain *variable references*.
  - For executables / batch files located in the *current directory*, a notable difference between `cmd.exe` and PowerShell is that the latter - by security-minded design - requires your to explicitly signal the intent to invoke the file there, using prefix `.\` (or `./`); e.g. while `cmd.exe` allows you to use `rabbitmqctl.bat` to invoke a batch file by that name in the current directory, PowerShell requires `.\rabbitmqctl.bat`
  - PowerShell's variable references, string literals and escaping rules differ from `cmd.exe`:

    - PowerShell supports *two* kinds of quoted string literals, [expandable (double-quoted) strings (**`"..."`**)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#double-quoted-strings) and [verbatim (single-quoted) strings (**`'...'`**)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#single-quoted-strings)
    - PowerShell's [escape character](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Special_Characters) is `` ` ``, the so-called *backtick*, where `cmd.exe` uses `^`
    - Variable references in PowerShell use sigil `$` and distinguish between PowerShell-only and *environment* variables (e.g, `$foo` and `$env:USERPROFILE`), compared to `cmd.exe`, which knows *only* environment variables and uses `%...%` syntax (e.g. `%USERPROFILE%`)
    - Compared to `cmd.exe`, PowerShell has different and more *metacharacters* (characters with special meaning), notably `` $ @ { } , ; ( ) ` ``. These enable many advanced features.

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed answer. Really helped.

Comment: I am glad to hear it, @TacyNathan; my pleasure.